# Is there a way to make these kind of query with multiple queries?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

```
@Query("select user.id, language, profile " +
            "from User user " +
            "join user.language language " +
            "left join user.profiles profile " +
            "where user.id in :usersIds")
    List<Object[]> findDataByUsersIds(@Param("usersIds") Collection<Integer> usersIds);
```

I would like a better way to write this query, by dividing it into multiple queries.